# how can i add a class to an element via JavaScript/JQuery, to style the element when the event of click happen on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoqtX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNBcr.png)`your text`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZErB.png)

Tried to add a class pre-styled when the click action happened.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrjaY.png)

how to add the line-through style to the element clicked using JavaScript/JQuery?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace e.target with whatever element it is you're trying to change.  Also, if you don't want to change the styling on repeated clicks, you can simply use addClass or removeClass

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function(e){

    $(e.target).toggleClass('stuff');

});
```

Comment: Or, if using `function() {` for the callback, `$(this).toggleClass..`

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer, here is a non-jQuery solution.

Assuming the elements in question are `<li>` type elements (if they're not, simply replace the `'li'` selector with the one you need):

```
// get all elements on which you would like to set 'click' event listeners
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('li');

// add 'click' event listeners to your elements
listItems.forEach((li) => {
    li.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (li.classList.contains('myClass')) {
            li.classList.remove('check');
        }
        else {
            li.classList.add('check');
        }        
    })
});
```

Similarly, as mentioned before, if you only want to add the class and not remove it on subsequent clicks, simply replace the whole `if else` statement with `li.classList.add('check');`.